# Scrapy: How to get all content HTML without "\n"

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi I have a problem on getting HTML code without **"\n"** I tried **normalize-space** function but it seems that it just getting the first paragraph (Not the whole message)

Here's the code that I am using

```
response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@class = 'messageContent'])").extract_first()
```

URL: https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-tsla-the-investment-world-the-2019-investors-roundtable.139047/

---

Without Normalize-space

```
<div> class="sample">\n
<span style="color:red;">Sample Message\n</span</div>
```

---

With Normalize-space

```
Sample Message
```

---

What I wanted is to also save the HTML code without "\n"

```
<div> class="sample">
<span style="color:red;">Sample Message</span</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to remove the newline character from the output, just do it:

```
response.xpath("//div[@class = 'messageContent']").extract_first().replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: Thanks @tomas that's all I need :)